# Inaccesable first column in pandas dataframe?

Tags: python, pandas, dataframe

I have a dataframe with multiple columns. When I execute the following code it assigns the header for the first column to the second column thereby making the first column inaccessible.

```
COLUMN_NAMES = ['id', 'diagnosis', 'radius_mean', 'texture_mean', 'perimeter_mean', 'area_mean',
   'smoothness_mean', 'compactness_mean', 'concavity_mean',
   'concave_points_mean', 'symmetry_mean', 'fractal_dimension_mean',
   'radius_se', 'texture_se', 'perimeter_se', 'area_se', 'smoothness_se',
   'compactness_se', 'concavity_se', 'concave_points_se', 'symmetry_se',
   'fractal_dimension_se', 'radius_worst', 'texture_worst',
   'perimeter_worst', 'area_worst', 'smoothness_worst',
   'compactness_worst', 'concavity_worst', 'concave_points_worst',
   'symmetry_worst']

TUMOR_TYPE = ['M', 'B']

path_to_file = list(files.upload().keys())[0]
data = pd.read_csv(path_to_file, names=COLUMN_NAMES, header=0)
print(data)



       id  diagnosis  ...  concave_points_worst  symmetry_worst
842302    M      17.99  ...                0.4601         0.11890
842517    M      20.57  ...                0.2750         0.08902
84300903  M      19.69  ...                0.3613         0.08758
```

The `id` tag is supposed to be associated with the first column but it's associated with the second one resulting in the last column header to get deleted.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

`pd.read_csv` is going to make your first column the index rather than a column like the rest of what is on your list.

You could update it to be:

```
path_to_file = list(files.upload().keys())[0]
data = pd.read_csv(path_to_file, names=COLUMN_NAMES, header=0,index_col = False)
```

to make sure that first column isn't treated as the index.